# static linking only some libraries

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries

How can I statically link only a some specific libraries to my binary when linking with GCC?

`gcc ... -static ...` tries to statically link **all** the linked libraries, but I haven't got the static version of some of them (eg: libX11).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use both static and dynamically linked libraries in gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809794/use-both-static-and-dynamically-linked-libraries-in-gcc)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`gcc -lsome_dynamic_lib code.c some_static_lib.a`

Comment: Link libraries after object files — especially static libraries.  In ancient and modern versions of the link environment (I'm not sure of the status quo for modestly old versions as of November 2010), listing the static library before the `code.c` file guarantees that the symbols in it will be ignored unless there happens to be a `main()` function in one of the library object files.

Comment: Coule you please elaborate on how this works? Code only answers are not helpfull for beginners.

Comment: @jb by default, gcc links dynamically.  When you use -lsome_dynamic_lib it gets linked dynamically as expected.  But, when gcc is given a static library explicitly, it will always try to link it statically.  There are, however, some tricky details about the order in which symbols get resolved; I'm not quite sure how that works.  I've learned that, when in doubt, try rearranging the order of library flags :-)

Comment: there is a lincense issue if you link statically  for example a [GPL library](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfLibraryIsGPL)

Comment: @HiB GPL applies the same way to static and dynamic linking

Comment: This doesn't work with `g++`, which doesn't honor the library search path to get the `.a` static library.

Comment: @vinc17 then pass it via `-Wl,-l:staticlib.a` ... the option is an `ld` option and not one of the gcc/g++ driver.

Answer (score 60):

You could also use `ld` option `-Bdynamic`

```
gcc <objectfiles> -static -lstatic1 -lstatic2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldynamic1 -ldynamic2
```

All libraries after it (including system ones linked by gcc automatically) will be linked dynamically.

Comment: -Wl,-Bdynamic requires GNU ld, so this solution doesn't work on systems where gcc uses the system ld (e.g. Mac OS X).

Answer (score 41):

```
gcc objectfiles -o program -Wl,-Bstatic -ls1 -ls2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -ld1 -ld2
```

you can also use: `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` flags for gcc libraries

keep in mind that if `libs1.so` and `libs1.a` both exists, the linker will pick `libs1.so` if it's before `-Wl,-Bstatic` or after `-Wl,-Bdynamic`. Don't forget to pass `-L/libs1-library-location/` before calling `-ls1`.

Comment: At least, this solution works to static link against libgomp!

Comment: This works well for me, while using `-static` somewhere in the command fails (I assume it tries to link more things statically than only the libraries I want).

Comment: NB. The order of `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` is important.

Answer (score 29):

From the manpage of `ld` (this does not work with gcc), referring to the `--static` option:

> You may use this option multiple
>   times on the command line: it affects
>   library searching for -l options which
>   follow it.

One solution is to put your dynamic dependencies before the `--static` option on the command line.

Another possibility is to not use `--static`, but instead provide the full filename/path of the static object file (i.e. not using -l option) for statically linking in of a specific library. Example:

```
# echo "int main() {}" > test.cpp
# c++ test.cpp /usr/lib/libX11.a
# ldd a.out
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff385cc000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9a5b233000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9a5afb0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9a5ad99000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9a5aa46000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9a5b53f000)
```

As you can see in the example, `libX11` is not in the list of dynamically-linked libraries, as it was linked statically.

Beware: An `.so` file is always linked dynamically, even when specified with a full filename/path.

Comment: What's the relationshop between libX11.a and the output of `ldd a.out`?

Comment: Ah, I see. `ldd` outputs the shared libraries required and libX11 doesn't appear on that list.

Comment: this isnt clear. you say 'this option' and 'that option'. what option?

Answer (score 19):

The problem as I understand it is as follows.  You have several libraries, some static, some dynamic and some both static and dynamic.  **gcc**'s default behavior is to link "mostly dynamic".  That is, **gcc** links to dynamic libraries when possible but otherwise falls back to static libraries.  When you use the **-static** option to **gcc** the behavior is to only link static libraries and exit with an error if no static library can be found, even if there is an appropriate dynamic library.

Another option, which I have on several occasions wished **gcc** had, is what I call **-mostly-static** and is essentially the opposite of **-dynamic** (the default).  **-mostly-static** would, if it existed, prefer to link against static libraries but would fall back to dynamic libraries.

This option does not exist but it can be emulated with the following algorithm:

1. Constructing the link command line with out including **-static**.
2. Iterate over the dynamic link options.
3. Accumulate library paths, i.e. those options of the form **-L<lib_dir>** in a variable **<lib_path>**
4. For each dynamic link option, i.e. those of the form **-l<lib_name>**, run the command **gcc <lib_path> -print-file-name=lib<lib_name>.a** and capture the output.
5. If the command prints something other than what you passed, it will be the full path to the static library.  Replace the dynamic library option with the full path to the static library.

Rinse and repeat until you've processed the entire link command line.  Optionally the script can also take a list of library names to exclude from static linking.

The following bash script seems to do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [--exclude <lib_name>]. . . <link_command>"
fi

exclude=()
lib_path=()

while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -L*)
            if [ "$1" == -L ]; then
                shift
                LPATH="-L$1"
            else
                LPATH="$1"
            fi

            lib_path+=("$LPATH")
            echo -n "\"$LPATH\" "
            ;;

        -l*)
            NAME="$(echo $1 | sed 's/-l\(.*\)/\1/')"

            if echo "${exclude[@]}" | grep " $NAME " >/dev/null; then
                echo -n "$1 "
            else
                LIB="$(gcc $lib_path -print-file-name=lib"$NAME".a)"
                if [ "$LIB" == lib"$NAME".a ]; then
                    echo -n "$1 "
                else
                    echo -n "\"$LIB\" "
                fi
            fi
            ;;

        --exclude)
            shift
            exclude+=(" $1 ")
            ;;

        *) echo -n "$1 "
    esac

    shift
done

echo
```

For example:

```
mostlyStatic gcc -o test test.c -ldl -lpthread
```

on my system returns:

```
gcc -o test test.c "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a" "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a"
```

or with an exclusion:

```
mostlyStatic --exclude dl gcc -o test test.c -ldl -lpthread
```

I then get:

```
gcc -o test test.c -ldl "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a"
```

Answer (score 15):

There is also `-l:libstatic1.a` (minus l colon) variant of -l option in gcc which can be used to link static library (Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728782). Is it documented? Not in the official documentation of gcc (which is not exact for shared libs too): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

> ```
> -llibrary
> -l library
> ```
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.) ... The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several directories.

The binutils ld doc describes it. The `-lname` option will do search for `libname.so` then for `libname.a` adding lib prefix and `.so` (if enabled at the moment) or `.a` suffix. But `-l:name` option will only search exactly for the name specified: 
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html

> ```
> -l namespec
> --library=namespec
> ```
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by `namespec` to the list of
>   files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If
>   `namespec` is of the form `:filename`, ld will search the library path
>   for a file called `filename`, otherwise it will search the library path
>   for a file called `libnamespec.a`.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for
>   files other than `libnamespec.a`. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>   systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
>   `libnamespec.so` before searching for one called `libnamespec.a`. (By
>   convention, a `.so` extension indicates a shared library.) Note that
>   this behavior does not apply to `:filename`, which always specifies a
>   file called `filename`.
>
> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.
>
> See the `-(` option for a way to force the linker to search archives
>   multiple times.
>
> You may list the same archive multiple times on the command line.
>
> This type of archive searching is standard for Unix linkers. However,
>   if you are using ld on AIX, note that it is different from the
>   behaviour of the AIX linker.

The variant `-l:namespec` is documented since 2.18 version of binutils (2007): https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/ld/Options.html

Comment: This option seems to work where everything else fails.
We just stumbled upon a case where we needed to static-link libjsoncpp.a, because our build machines would produce binaries linked  against libjsocpp.so.0, whereas target OS provides only libjsoncpp.so.1. Until we can clear up this difference, this was the only solution that yielded proper results in our case.

Answer (score 4):

Some loaders (linkers) provide switches for turning dynamic loading on and off.  If GCC is running on such a system (Solaris - and possibly others), then you can use the relevant option.

If you know which libraries you want to link statically, you can simply specify the static library file in the link line - by full path.

Comment: Even though this answer was accepted it does not address the problem fully.  As @peoro explained the problem he is trying to solve is that he does not have static versions of all the libraries which implies that he would like to link as many libraries statically as possible.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

to link dynamic and static library within one line, you must put static libs *after* dynamic libs and object files, like this:

`gcc -lssl main.o -lFooLib -o main`

otherwise, it will not work. it does take me sometime to figure it out.