# OpenGL SOIL Undefined reference to glBindTexture, glTexImage2d, etc

Tags: c++, opengl, reference, undefined, soil

I'm using C++ and Opengl, and I'm trying to use SOIL, but when I compile, I get undefined reference to glBindTexture, glTexImage2D, etc. However, this is only coming from SOIL.c, not my own source code. This is what the error produces:

http://pastebin.com/sKrQaBhz

My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680 and my drivers are fully updated. I have everything linked and I'm using premake to manage my project. I'm developing on a linux machine, however, I'm trying to cross compile it onto my windows machine, which gives this error. If I compile it on linux, it's completely fine. This is my premake4.lua file:

http://pastebin.com/T4hsbdz0

My include files is this:

```
#include "opengl/gl_core_3_3.hpp"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "loadshader.hpp"
```

I'm using mingw32 to compile my code. Before I was using SOIL, everything was fine. I downloaded SOIL from their webpage at lonesock.net, which I then copied over the libSOIL.a and their include files, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe try compiling the .a file instead of copying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links order matters for g++.
Try this order:

> links { "SOIL", "glfw3", "opengl32", "gdi32", "glu32" }

(edit: fixed the OP answer according to the duplicated question in Premake forum: http://industriousone.com/topic/how-use-premake-compile-static-library)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at SOIL homepage, they said that it must be linked staticly. So, instead of using dynamic linking ('-l' in gcc compiler), try to specify the full path of the library.

This post illustrate what I want to say: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156190/2293156

> gcc -lsome_dynamic_lib some_static_lib.a code.c