# Create shared .so library that has all it's dependencies statically linked

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

I am trying to build my `.so` library with all dependencies (mostly boost) statically linked. Currently, I can build statically linked static library and dynamically linked shared library:

[image: image description]

I would like to add other dependencies to `.so` library so that it has 20MB and does not require user to install anything. Note that this is just a temporary solution before we upgrade to new Boost 1.55 on production servers.

I define libraries like this in Makefile (`$ARCH` can be either 32 or 64):

```
## Multi-arch library locations
LIB32=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
LIB64=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBDIR:=$(LIB$(ARCH))
##Library directory
LIB=-L $(LIBDIR)
## DYNAMIC
LIBS=-lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_signals -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -llog4cplus -lcrypto -lssl -lm
## STATIC
SLIBS=$(LIBDIR)libboost_serialization.a $(LIBDIR)libboost_thread.a $(LIBDIR)libboost_date_time.a $(LIBDIR)libboost_signals.a $(LIBDIR)libboost_iostreams.a $(LIBDIR)libboost_system.a $(LIBDIR)liblog4cplus.a
```

### Shared lib with dynamic linking:

This is my shared lib GCC command:

- **Makefile:**

  ```
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LIB) $(LIBS) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(SHARED_LIB_VERSION) -o $(NEW_LIB_DIR)${SHARED_LIB_VERSION} $(OBJ_CPP_DYN) $(OBJ_C_DYN)
  ```
- Changes into:

  ```
  g++ -m64 -Wl,--trace -D NDEBUG -I /usr/include/ -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -shared -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_signals -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -llog4cplus -lcrypto -lssl -lm -Wl,-soname,libLIBNAMEx64.so -o ../Release/libLIBNAMELIBNAMEx64.so ... and much more .o files ...
  ```
- Linker says:

  ```
  -lboost_serialization (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libboost_serialization.so)
  -lboost_thread (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libboost_thread.so)
  -lboost_date_time (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libboost_date_time.so)
  -lboost_signals (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libboost_signals.so)
  -lboost_iostreams (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libboost_iostreams.so)
  -lboost_system (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libboost_system.so)
  -llog4cplus (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//liblog4cplus.so)
  -lcrypto (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libcrypto.so)
  -lssl (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libssl.so)
  ```

And it works.

### Shared lib with *static* linking:

I thought I can just replace `-shared` with `-static`:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,--trace -D NDEBUG -I /usr/include/ -I /usr/local/include  -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -static -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_signals -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -llog4cplus -lcrypto -lssl -lm -Wl,-soname,libLIBNAMEx64_static_link.so -o ../Release/libLIBNAMEx64_static_link.so ... and much more .o files ...
```

But I get **`undefined reference`** errors everywhere.

So where do I configure how are dependencies linked with my binary? How can I achieve my goal?

### More things I tried (edit)

#### [`-Wl,--library`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

I also tried passing libraries directly to linker in a very assertive manner:

```
-Wl,--library=:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.a
```

And without `:` (which prevents searching for `.a`):

```
 -Wl,--library=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.a
```

But I get the error:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.a
```

Of course, the file exists at that path.

#### [Pass just library names:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156190/607407)

Of course, here it's not even interpreted as linking command:

```
g++: error: libboost_serialization.a: No such file or directory
```

Interesting is that if I pass full path instead (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.a`), GCC doubles it:

```
g++: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156055/gcc-static-linking-only-some-libraries) not cover your problem?

Comment: `g++: error: libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory` - nope, it doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I have both static `.a` and dynamic `.so` boost libraries. Same applies to the others I'm using. As I said, statically linked static lib compiles without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use command `man ld`, I got this information:

> -static
>
> Do not link against shared libraries. It affects library searching for `-l` options which follow it. This option also implies `--unresolved-symbols=report-all`. This option can be used with `-shared`. Doing so means that a shared library is being created but that all of the library's external references must be resolved by pulling in entries from static libraries.

This option is exactly what you want: create a shared library with all dependencies (mostly boost) statically linked.

`-l` parameter is used to specify the library name, so you should use `boost_serialization` instead of `/path/libboost_serialization.a`:

> -larchive
>
> If you specify `-lcommon`, then ld will search its path-list for occurrences of "libcommon.a" for every `common` specified.

You can use `-L` parameter many times to specify the library paths when ld try to search static libraries:

> -Lsearchdir

For example:
`-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Answer (score 0):

You could try `-Wl,--whole-archive ${your library} -Wl,--no-whole-archive`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I pass the library paths then? Full path seems to cause problems: `-l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.a` results in: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.a`.