# How to Combine .so and executable in one .so file

Tags: opencv, g++, executable, .so

For my project, I am using openCV library api in my source code. SO I optimized the module of opencv library (I keep only required module ie: core,imgcodecs,imgproc,highgui,ml and videoio) and I combined these modules together and I created one .so file.Now I have one .so and one executable.
My question is how to combine this .so and executable and create one .so file.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to [link with static libraries (.a)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4156055/2286337) not dynamic ones (.so).

Comment: `.so` are considered by compiler as final product i don't think this is possible