# Link glibc statically but some other library dynamically with GCC

Tags: c, linker, glibc, static-linking

I need to statically link glibc to my project, because the target platform supports only a very old one ( but it works with statically linked glibc from my toolchain, I have checked it)

Unfortunately, this application has to make use of pthread library, but statically linked libpthread takes too much space.

I would like to statically link glibc, and dynamically pthread.

After running this command

```
powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc object_files -lrt -lpthread -Wl,-Bstatic -lc
```

I get:

```
/powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

Comment: You'll need to add `-Wl,-Bdynamic` after the `-lc`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry it was my mistake. I wanted to link glibc statically

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809794/use-both-static-and-dynamically-linked-libraries-in-gcc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a `-static-libgcc` if that may help

Comment: @nkdm then you need to go with R..'s suggestion of uclibc

Comment: For the record libgcc is not glibc (which is what the title of this SO question is about). glibc is the GNU implementation of the C standard library. libgcc is part of the gcc internals and is used by gcc "whenever it needs to perform some operation that is too complicated to emit inline code for".

Comment: Why is this answer accepted since it's completely wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You should be using `-static`, not `-Wl,-static`. The latter bypasses gcc's knowledge, and therefore gcc is still trying to link the shared `libgcc_s.so` rather than the static `libgcc_eh.a`.

If your aim is to link libc statically but libpthread dynamically, this is simply not going to work. You cannot mix and match different versions of libpthread; it's part of glibc, just a separate file, and the internals need to match. Even with the same version, I think linking libc statically and libpthread dynamically will be very broken.

If glibc is too big for your needs, you could try an alternate libc like [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org) or [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org).

Comment: But I need to have lpthread linked dynamically. The -static option will link everything statically.