# Static executable compiling error : undefined reference to

Tags: c, linux, arm

I am trying to compile a simple "hello world" program using a complete and stable GCC 4.4.0. Every thing is OK when I try to compile a dynamic executable but when I try to compile the static executable one, I get error "undefined reference to printf". It's the same in every program I try to compile in static mode. It can not recognize libc functions. Even with "`-nostdlib`" or "`-lc`" it's the same!  Also "`-L ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`" does not fix it.

```
./ccL10382.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `printf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do?

Comment: with/without `-nostdlib` I got same error

Comment: I guess -static option does not work for you, does it? `gcc -Wall -static -g -o test test.c`

Comment: `# gcc -Wall -static -g -o test test.c
test.c:2: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
/system/android-gcc-4.4.0/sysroot/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o: In function `_start':
bionic/libc/arch-arm/bionic/crtbegin_dynamic.S:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__libc_init'
./ccx11630.o: In function `main':                    /data/a/ts/test.c:2: undefined reference to `printf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static linking glibc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187499/static-linking-glibc)

Comment: @alk , I can not find any similarity between my question and the one in the link you mentioned !

Answer (score 0):

At the first, look into libc.a. Looks like it should be in /system/android-gcc-4.4.0/sysroot/usr/lib/.
So you need to execute:

**nm /system/android-gcc-4.4.0/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.a | grep printf**

If printf is present, you have a problem with link parameters. It can be verified by adding flag **-v** to gcc command line. Check output carefully to know what the libc links exactly.