# Is it possible to downgrade glibc on OpenSUSE?

Tags: c++, linux, glibc, opensuse

I want to run a C++ program on an older device, which only supports glibc 2.11.3. So I have to create a develloping enviroment using the same glibc version.

Currently it is running version 2.25 x86_64 for openSUSE Tumbleweed.

First of all, where do I find a valid *.rpm file of the old version. Also is it possible to install it?

Trying to unistall glibc tells me that will crash the operation system. :-)

Thank you all for your support.

Comment: Look for instructions on setting up a chroot environment for that version. A chroot is a completely independent set of user-space programs and libraries in which programs can run independent of your main system. You could do this with a cross-compiler, but I've always found a chroot to be easier to set up.

Comment: You should not downgrade your system libc. Instead, install the older version in a seperate directory tree, and develop against that. It's not too difficult to compile glibc from source so I would suggest doing that.

Comment: glibc 2.11.3 comes with OpenSUSE 11.4. You can get the distribution iso and individual rpms from [gwdg.de (University of Goettingen Computing Centre)](https://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/discontinued/distribution/11.4/)

Comment: @DarkFalcon you wouldn't need to go as far as using a cross-compiler for this case, I think. It should just be a matter of linking against the older libc.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the system glibc will almost certainly result in a disaster. I think you have 2 solutions:
[multiple glibc on one system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)
or [link glibc statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187499/link-glibc-statically-but-some-other-library-dynamically-with-gcc)

Comment: The first question you link is about running a program against another versions of libc; this question is about linking to one, IIUC. It's actually quite a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Trying to unistall glibc tells me that will crash the operation system. :-)

I don't understand your smiley.

It will render your system unbootable, yes.

What you want to do is best achieved in one of several ways:

1. Create a Linux-to-older-Linux cross-compiler
2. Create a "older Linux" chroot environment (ChromeOS uses this approach)
3. Create a "older Linux" virtual machine, and develop inside of it.

Approach 2 is likely easiest to set up, closely followed by approach 3.

Approach 1 gives you the best build performance, but requires thorough understanding of how to build cross-compilers.