# Does gcc link program with static or dynamic library by default?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, linker

I have both static and dynamic versions of the same library installed on my Linux system:

```
/usr/lib/libsample.a
/usr/lib/libsample.so
```

Which one of these libraries will use gcc, if I set argument -lsample ?

```
gcc xxx.c -lsample
```

How can I force gcc to use static or dynamic version of the library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.htm

You don't have to do anything, dynamic is the default.

However, it has to add a couple of things to the binary to help it, at runtime, to properly use the dynamic library.

Comment: ok, dynamic will be used by default, but how to say compiler to use static library? If I use "-static" it will links only static libraries. Is there any way to link only particular static library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809794/use-both-static-and-dynamically-linked-libraries-in-gcc

Comment: One way is just directly specify path to `.a` (without any `-llibname` - just path to file, like ordinary `.o`). Other way is `-Wl,-static -llibname -Wl,-Bdynamic` (first command sets linker to use static, third reverts back to dynamic).