# Is it possible to compile statically with gcc or g++ on Linux based systems?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I am working on a project which I would like to be able to "ship" to other Linux based computers as a complete executable with no dependencies. (In order that I can copy just the 1 file to other systems, and then run that file on those systems.)

In the windows world, I think static linking is done just by passing `-static` to the compiler, perhaps with some other options for specific libraries*, if you are using Visual Studio.

*eg: Using SFML you also have to define SFML_STATIC for some reason?

Is this possible using gcc / g++, and if so how? I tried searching for this but didn't manage to find anything. I have heard before that this may be a non-trivial task.

Edits:

BasileStarynkevitch suggested compiling with the flag `-static`.

I don't know if this is what I want, but I wrote a test program to try it out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Link statically please" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And then compiled with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o a.out -static
g++ main.cpp -o b.out
```

The results are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1  1653098  a.out
-rwxr-xr-x  1     9167  b.out
```

So it looks like it might be working?

TonyD suggested a method of checking:

```
ldd a.out 
not a dynamic executable

ldd b.out
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3d5ac000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fce5e34a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fce5df85000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fce5dc7e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fce5e677000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fce5da67000)
```

Comment: It could be possible, but it might be unreasonable. Did you try to use `g++ -static` on Linux?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can you elaborate on this point?

Comment: Did you consider publishing your code as free software?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, because some of the system binding libraries like glibc might be different on a different linux system. The usual way is to ship source packages and configure and compile them on the target system.

Comment: It's a good question, but no research effort....

Comment: @TonyD I did google it, but didn't manage to find anything.

Comment: @user3728501 [sure?](https://www.google.de/search?q=linux+program+shipping&rlz=1Y3KTZR_deDE555DE555&oq=linux+program+shipping&aqs=chrome..69i57.36924j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Hmmm... "GCC static" / feeling lucky works ok for me... in those docs - could at least explore `-static` and `-static-lib*` and explain how they meet or don't meet your needs.  Anyway, given you now say you've created an `a.out` you suspect might work, why not use `ldd` to list the dynamic dependencies, as well as try it on some of the boxes you want to deploy to?

Comment: @TonyD I was not aware of the command ldd

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why would I publish my code as free software? It isn't useful to anyone? This is a ridiculous question to ask. I want to move my code form machine to machine, within my organization - not sell it.

Comment: Because then you put the burden of compilation & packaging on users & distribution makers

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What you are saying may be true but is not relevant in the context of what I want to do. I am not shipping anything on mass or to sell. I am just running several copies of a program, some of which someone else is running for me on different hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling with `-static` appears to work for basic c++ programs, probably all of the standard library?

However when using with other libraries, this may no longer work.

Answer (score 15):

> Is it possible to compile statically with gcc or g++ on Linux based systems?

It depends.

You might try to compile and link all your code with `gcc -static` or `g++ -static`. In several cases (e.g. pure command-line applications, like your hello world), it would work.

Linux distributions like a lot shared libraries. Most of them are using shared libraries extensively (notably for graphical applications). Read Drepper's [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper for more.

You might have some licensing issues. To simplify outrageously, it might be illegal (against the [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-3.0.en.html) license) to ship code *statically* linked to some LGPL (or GPL) library. The evil is in the details.

Some core features, notably DNS related (e.g. [getaddrinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) & [getnameinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html)) are internally using plugin techniques à la [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), so sort-of requires a *dynamic* `libc.so`  (see [nsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) for more).

Some [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) things, in particular font related, are also expecting plugin related things (IIRC, Xft); perhaps SFML uses them. BTW, SFML is very probably installed as shared libraries, so you'll need to rebuild SFML from source code...

At last, a statically linked program might be more tied to some particular kernel version that a dynamically linked one (in principle, this is not the case). It might happen that you could have incompatibilities with very old or future kernels (but usually not).

See also [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html), [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)

It might be actually simpler to ship the source code to the target system, ask the sysadmin to install required dependencies, and build your code on the remote target (e.g. using `ssh`)

You could try to link statically most libraries but not all (e.g. link statically `libstdc++.a` and dynamically `libc.so`) by playing with [GCC linking options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578558/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816138/841108)

Perhaps you'll first should try to link statically some SFML demo.... or simply `scp` your (dynamically linked) binary program and try to run it remotely (it might be able to run).