# C user-defined error codes instead of enum or defines

Tags: c, error-handling

One of the standard approaches in C error handling code is that functions return an error code, which must then be handled by the calling code. I often see libraries with a header file containing a big enum or a ton of `#define`s to define error codes. This header file must then be included in each user source file using the library's functions to do the error handling.

This approach has the drawback that whenever an error code is added or removed, all source files that include the header with the error code definitions must be recompiled. OK, this does not happen very often, but can be annoying when a new release of the library is rolled out.

Another drawback is that it is somewhat cumbersome to handle different error codes at once. For instance errors that have different causes (hence different error codes) but need to be handled the same way.

There is an alternative which allows users to assign an arbitrary value to error codes returned by the library: All error codes used by a module are declared in its header file as `extern const uint16_t MY_ERROR_CODE;`. The user then must define these values.

For instance for a library named `MyLib` with two modules `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`, the API would be

```
/// my_lib_module_a.h

extern const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_A_PARAM_RANGE;
extern const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_A_FOO;

uint16_t my_lib_module_a_do_smth(...);
```

and

```
/// my_lib_module_b.h

extern const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_B_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
extern const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_B_BAR;

uint16_t my_lib_module_b_do_smth(...);
```

The user code would then define the error codes without needing to include anything (except `stdint.h` of course)

```
/// error_codes.c

const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_A_PARAM_RANGE   = 1u;
const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_A_FOO           = 2u; 
const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_B_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 3u;
const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_B_BAR           = 4u;
...
```

The advantages I see from this approach are:

- The modules in my library are decoupled with respect to the error code: they only know the error codes they use.
- The user can decide to give the same value to different errors so they can be handled the same way.

Of course, there are some drawbacks:

- Each error code eats up some memory because there is an actual variable to hold the error code's value. However, it would need about 2 bytes per error code, which would be around 100B if 50 error codes are used overall. Even on small microcontrollers, I think this is bearable.
- The approach might not be very intuitive.

**Are there other drawbacks I missed?**

Comment: The main drawback is that it does not make too much sense. 1, If you want to handle different codes the same way simply add some logic into your program. 2. Every check requires reading the memory. 3. It is very hard to manage 4. Error prone 5. Adds completely not needed overhead.  Think why everyone is using the "traditional" way. Are all experienced programmers stupid?

Comment: 1. This also means overhead, 2. agree, 3. Why? You need one single .c file to define your error codes. How is this hard to manage? 4. Don't you write unit tests? 5.  Yes, the developer must take time and assign a value to each error code. During runtime, see (1) and (2).

Answer (score 1):

Typically you have a program, created by the user, and a library, created by a vendor. The program depends on the library: the linker resolves undefined symbols in the program using defined symbols in the library.

In the model you propose, the dependency is two-way: the library has undefined symbols which the linker should resolve using the program. This is non-standard, so expect problems!

Some linkers will require command-line options to handle this two-way dependency. Regardless of the linker's specifics, this unnatural dependency will make it annoying to add error codes: if the new version of the library can return a new error, e.g. `ERR_MODULE_A_BAZ`, the user should update the program with something like `extern const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_A_BAZ = 97`.

All this assumed you used static linking. What happens if you use dynamic-linking? I don't know what exactly, but nothing good.

Comment: `extern const uint16_t ERR_MODULE_A_BAZ = 97.` try it

Comment: There will not be problems linking

Comment: @anatolyg There are many libraries with undefined symbols. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33861937/21965131. A library is just a collection of object files, so why should this two-way dependency be a problem?
Regarding dynamic linking, I did not think of that since I had small embedded systems in mind, where dynamic linking is typically not used.