# Is gcc -lc linking to static or dynamic library? How to make sure I only link to dynamic?

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic, static, linker

Seems there's both libc.a and libc.so, right?

> (1) If both exists, which does '-l' prefer?
>
> (2) How do I specify I prefer the .so version against .a version, any gcc/g++ command line option to do this?

Comment: Refer its first answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809794/use-both-static-and-dynamically-linked-libraries-in-gcc

Comment: I found in my ubuntu 1604, there're both : ./usr/lib32/libc.a and ./usr/lib32/libc.so. Then which one is used, "a" or "so"?