# How to build CGO program static linking to glibc and dynamic linking to libGL.so?

Tags: go, opengl, glibc, cgo

My os is Kali, running GLIBC_2.32. I need to build an CGO application for a debian 10 system, which is running GLIBC_2.28.

If I `go build` with dynamic linking, it can't be run on the debian system, it shows GLIBC mismatch:

```
version `GLIBC_2.29` not found
version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` not found
version `GLIBC_2.32` not found
```

So I tried static linking: `CGO_LDFLAGS='-static' go build`. A gui library uses OpenGL and it shows error:

```
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

After searching a while I found the libGL is related to the gpu driver and can't be statically linked.

Then I tried linking libGL.so dynamically and statically linking other libraries by:

`CGO_LDFLAGS='-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Bdynamic -lGL -static' go build`

But same error: "cannot find -lGL"

I don't want to use docker, it's too heavy. And I don't think upgrading from debian 10 to 11 solves the problem, there maybe some other clients running different os in the future. What's the best solution?

Comment: Even if statically linked, glibc needs to match on the host system (which is generally why you shouldn’t statically link glibc). There are some c libraries like musl intended for static linking.

Answer (score 2):

> Then I tried linking libGL.so dynamically and statically linking other libraries by:
> `CGO_LDFLAGS='-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Bdynamic -lGL -static' go build`

The `-static` flag tells the linker: perform a *completely* static link. It doesn't matter whether you put it before or after `-lGL`, the meaning is the same.

To link some libraries statically and link others dynamically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816138/50617).

That said, what you are trying to do is impossible: if you have *any* dynamic libraries in your link, then `libc.so.6` *must* also be dynamically linked.

> I don't want to use docker, it's too heavy.

Too bad. You'll have to use docker, or set up a `chroot` environment, or build yourself a "Linux to older Linux" crosscompiler. The docker is likely easiest to implement.