# g++ creates shared object with dynamic dependency even though I gave it a static archive in the inputs

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have a source file, `mything.cpp`, and a library that was provided to me as `notmine.h` and `notmine.a`.

I need to produce a shared object that has all my stuff from `mything.cpp` and all the stuff from `somelib.a`. Here is what I did on the command line:

```
g++ -fpic -c -o mything.o mything.cpp
g++ -shared -o mything.so mything.o notmine.a
```

However, when I look at the final `mything.so` using `ldd` I see that it has a dependency on `libnotmine.so`, and when I check `nm`, I see that all the symbols that should have been supplied by `notmine.a` are undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

---

More details: `notmine.a` is actually `liblua.a` that I built locally. I think g++ might be getting confused because there is a `liblua.so` in the system directories

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. There are two options. The simpler is to use:

```
g++ -fpic -c -o mything.o mything.cpp
g++ -shared -o mything.so mything.o -L. -l:notmine.a
```

Alternatively, you can tell the linker you want to treat the `.a` as a bunch of object files with

```
g++ -fpic -c -o mything.o mything.cpp
g++ -shared -o mything.so mything.o -Wl,--whole_archive notmine.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

The `--Wl,-no-whole-archive` is to prevent that flag from messing up the other steps the linker does with the system libraries

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/816138/50617